# Django: Unable to see value from database in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm a newbie at extracting values from the DB via views and templates but all of my attempts have failed so far. I've been looking at this for several hours now.
I have the below model in my users app at models.py. This is an additional model to the "main one" with the regular name, email and password for my users.

```
class WorkEmail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    work_email = models.EmailField(unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
    work_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    work_email_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verified_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    request_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.work_email
```

I have this UpdateView in views.py that works perfectly (with the exception of being able to see whether the work email has been verified or not, i.e. from the line with work_is_verified, till the end.

```
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView): 
    form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'update_profile.html'
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
    def work_is_verified(self, request):
        if request.work_email_verified==True and request.work_email_active==True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And I have the below, in my update profile template at update_profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
  </form>
  <h2>Verification </h2>
  <p> {{user.work_is_verified}} </p>
  {% if user.work_is_verified == True %}
  <a href="{% url 'verified_company_deletion' %}">Delete Work Email and Verified Company Name</a> 
  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'verify_company' %}">Verify Company Name via Work Email</a> 
  {% endif %} 
  <p></p> 
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Template works and I'm able to change the values of my main form (customuserchangeform) BUT that method that I created in my view to check if the email is verified and active for a user is not doing anything... (not even showing up).
I want to be able to make a logic that gives either a True or a False whenever we're checking that a user's records in that table show the email being both, verified and active. I should say that this model/table could have many rows for the same user, but the way we can identify the most up-to-date work email is by filtering by both, work_email_active and work_email_verified.

{{user.work_is_verified}}

{% if user.work_is_verified == True %}

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For email in request.user.workmail_set:
    if email.workmail.work_email_verified and email.workmail.work_email_active:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I've also tried, the below without luck. Thank you.                 
           `    def work_is_verified(self, request):
        if request.WorkEmail.work_email_verified == True and request.WorkEmail.work_email_active == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False`

Comment: This may be because we are getting a queryset. If your user has one work email, I suggest you use the OneToOne field to link the user instead of using Foreign key.

Comment: That does not work and your syntax is inaccurate ... thank you for trying though.